# can somebody explain what " self.preorder_print(self.root, "")[:-1] " line is doing here inside the print_tree function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I understand slice notation. But need some help here.

Below code traverses and prints a binary tree. Can somebody explain what `self.preorder_print(self.root, "")[:-1]` line is doing here inside the `print_tree` function?

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = Node(root)

    def search(self, find_val):
        return self.preorder_search(self.root, find_val)

    def print_tree(self):
        return self.preorder_print(self.root, "")[:-1]

    def preorder_search(self, start, find_val):
        if start:
            if start.value == find_val:
                return True
            else:
                return self.preorder_search(start.left, find_val) or self.preorder_search(start.right, find_val)
        return False

    def preorder_print(self, start, traversal):
        if start:
            traversal += ("-" + str(start.value))
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.right, traversal)
        return traversal
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. Possibly highglight the problematic part in its own block too.

Comment: This is a binary tree code. Preorder_print() funtion has to print the tree in a pre-order way. I did not understand the line "return self.preorder_print(self.root, "")[:-1]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [:-1] is a slice notation, it allow to take a subsection of those object that implement it, the use is as follow [start:end:step] *start* is the initial position you want to start taking elements, likewise *end* is where to stop, if negative it would count that many position from the end, useful if you don't know how long is the object, *step* allow to skip elements if different than one and/or take it in reverse if negative, each one can be omitted, in which case they take appropriates default values

for example

```
>>> "123"[:-1]
'12'
>>>
```

is to remove the last element, so in your case as `preorder_print` return a string, with the [:-1] it remove the last character

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/5644961) you can find more about slice notation

Comment: so if there is a statement like this - 

"some string"[:-1]  

then result will be "some strin" removing the "g" ?????

Comment: Yes. You can play with it in your python console